# VS2015: How to hide the 'References' folder in solution explorer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2015, and from past experiences there are a few folders that some people generally don't want, excitedly, these (red):

[image]

But, I managed to get it down by selecting 'Disable External Dependencies folder' folder option to true, and got this:

[image]

But I cannot find any option to disable the leftover virtual folder, how can I disable the 'References' folder?

Comment: Have you tried  to click on the Project menu and uncheck "Show All Files"?

Comment: It is unchecked :) And if I check it there's just more unneeded entries.

Comment: What is exactly your project Type? Do you have this issue in all project types? Another clue, sometimes some external plugins "screws up" the IDE, so make sure you are using stable plugins only.

Comment: This is in a default VS2015 install. in all C++ projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think disabling the references folder is possible yet.  [This uservoice suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12345891-add-option-to-disable-references-folder-in-solut) is called "Add option to disable References folder in Solution Explorer tab" and is still open.

Answer (score 0):

this is a default option in visual studio and you can't hide it.
you can **set scope** to special folder or make a **new view** of your solution explorer instead of remove or hide a part of solution explorer

Comment: Without a bit more explantion or a link this is a pretty useless reply.

Answer (score 0):

I feel yor pain, HATE that view.
You can disable it in the Options dialog (from the Tools menu).

On the right side panel expand the **Text Editor** section, then expand **C/C++** and then click on **Advanced**. Set the **Disable External Dependencies Folder** to True and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I've set it to 'Hidden' but the References folder is still visible. It's different from 'Dependencies', unfortunately.